# KNN for spatial data and two sets of coordinates

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, knn, spdep

I'm trying to estimate an average value of distances to K nearest neighbors. I have two sets of coordinates and I'm trying to estimate the average distance from each point in one set of coordinates to the K nearest neighbors in the other set of coordinates.

The following post is instructive in how this could be done when the neighbors are from the same set of coordinates: [Simple KNN for spatial data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412772/simple-knn-for-spatial-data)

But in my case I have two sets representing different feature types and I would like to know the average distance between each observation of one feature type with the K nearest neighbors of the other feature type.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like the `get.knnx` function from the `FNN` package:

```
  get.knnx(data, query, k=10, algorithm=c("kd_tree", "cover_tree",
               "CR", "brute"))
```

It returns the `k` points in `data` that are nearest to each point in `query`.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick!